# How to test Request/Response encoding in asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding

I was asked to change Encoding type in asp.net web application to UTF-8

So made changes as per recommended setting. 
added encoding type in Web config.

```
<globalization

  requestEncoding="utf-8" 
  responseEncoding="utf-8"    />
```

Can you please guide me how I can test change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the site with Fiddler before the change and after. See whether the site now returns `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` as one of the response headers, and whether non-ASCII characters are shown correctly" - e.g. this "`☃`" should be a snowman, not a `?` or the "missing character" square.